# want to create custom rule for like post or comment?

Tags: rules

I want to write a code for custom rule.I want to that when some one post a comment then one can able to like his/her post or comment i.e a single click on the Like will 'like' pieces of content and a message is send to that user who posted that comment . Is it possible with rules ??

Comment: for liking are u using voting api or flag?

Comment: nothing till ...which would be best to use . ? i just want something similar to "facebook like". Is it possible by creating a custom rule ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.

> Def: Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely
>   customizable by the administrator. Using this module, the site
>   administrator can provide any number of flags for nodes, comments,
>   users, and any other type of entity.

Once you install the module, its very simple. Goto structure->flag->add new flag. Give title for the flag and use the count option to display the like-count.

In my example, 'Node Like' is the title of the flag, the flag count can be achieved in token

```
[node:flag-node-like-count]
```

[image]

*To answer your question, its possible but complex to achieve just using rules.*

Comment: great....i will try this too..